# PyQT: Using attributes from SQLite query

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I am confused as to how I can use certain attributes that are returned after a query to a local SQLite database. I can populate a qlistwidget with one of the attributes but I do not know how to get the other attributes when a user clicks on the listwidget item.

The following code was created using Eric which pre populates some of the signals and slots

```
@pyqtSignature("QString")
def on_searchText_textEdited(self, p0):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    # TODO: not implemented yet
    self.resultsList.clear()
    self.searchItem = self.searchText.text()
    self.search()


@pyqtSignature("QListWidgetItem*")
def on_resultsList_itemClicked(self, item):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    # TODO: not implemented yet

    result = str(item.text())
    QMessageBox.about(self, "Clicked Item", "%s")%(result)


@pyqtSignature("")
def on_cancelButton_clicked(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    self.close()

def search(self):

    conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\file.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlqry = "SELECT name, number, size FROM lookup WHERE name LIKE '%s' LIMIT 100;"%("%"+self.searchItem+"%")

    try:
        c = cur.execute(sqlqry)
        data = c.fetchall()            
        for i in data:                
            self.resultsList.addItem(i[0])

    except sqlite3.Error, e:

        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error message", "Error")
```

So my resultsList gets populated when the user enters text into the line edit but then when a user clicks on an item I get an error with the messagebox saying something about a NoneType and str.

However, what I really need to use are the second and third attributes for somewhere else in my code.

So how do I select that attributes through the itemClicked signal and create two new variables?

i hope that makes sense, it has been a long day going round in circles

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query from the database again and work with the new row.

```
@pyqtSignature("QListWidgetItem*")
def on_resultsList_itemClicked(self, item):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """

    result = str(item.text())
    QMessageBox.about(self, "Clicked Item", "%s")%(result)

    conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\file.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlqry = "SELECT name, number, size FROM lookup WHERE name = '%s' LIMIT 1;"%(result)

    try:
        c = cur.execute(sqlqry)
        data = c.fetchone()            
        # Do something with data

    except sqlite3.Error, e:

        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error fetching %s"%name, "Error")
```

Obviously, this doesn't deal with the database santisation issues you might have, and assumes that `name` is unique in the database.